# How can I use each line of a file as an input switch in bash?

Tags: bash, line

I have a file that contains a list of filenames on each line.

myfile.txt:

```
somepath/Documents/a.txt
somepath/Documents/b.txt
somepath/Documents/c.txt
```

This file can contain any number of lines.  What I want to do is then run a command that runs cat with each line being an input, such as:

```
cat <line 1> <line 2> <line 3> new_combination_file.txt
```

I was looking this up and I *think* I should be using xargs to do this, but when I looked up examples and the man page, it didn't make sense to me.  Can someone help?

Comment: Bad example in description. I'll edit the description. I have the absolute path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `while read` loop to read each line into a variable

```
while read -r filename
do
    cat "$filename"
done < myfile.txt > new_combination_file.txt
```

You can also use `xargs`:

```
xargs cat < myfile.txt > new_combination_file.txt
```

However, this won't work if any filenames contain spaces.

Comment: Is it really that simple?!? Wouldn't the "cat "$filename" run once each time overwriting the $filename variable?  I suppose if it's cat, then it just displays everything, huh?

Also, thank you for the xargs way as well! I'll try both in a bit and get back to you (and mark answer if it works for me)!

Comment: `cat` inherits its standard output from the `while` loop, which opens the file and keeps it open thoughout the iteration. The output of each `cat` process is written sequentially to the output file.

Comment: `$filename` gets each line of `myfile.txt`. The entire output of the loop gets written to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `xargs` command, just use

```
cat myfile.txt | xargs -I {} cat {}
```

`-I` specifies that the following command will be executed for each line of the input (that is, `cat myfile.txt` in this example) and

`{}` represents the value of each line

If you want to combine the output produced just use the regular redirect `>` command followed by the filename.

Hope this helps.

Comment: xargs seems really useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` to do this like so:

```
xargs -t -a myfile.txt cat >new_combination_file.txt
```